# json_decode in php for the webservice url (url gives the data)

Tags: php

My problem is I have one web-service which return the data in the json format
I am using the following code to access the data

```
 if ($datas = file_get_contents($url))
     return json_decode($datas);
 return Array('error' => "Can't open url");

//data when url is accessed in the browser
{"d":[[6.082,245]]}
```

I am getting the error can't open url.
I am not getting the problem.Somehow I am not able to access the json_decode data and there are some function which are using the same functionality and the those are able to access the data

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($datas)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the url is correct and valid, And try to check for the errors on error.log for the errors on file_get_contents

Note:  file_get_contents() returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to maxlen bytes. On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

if the above condition is true check with this,

Try printing json data

var_dump(json_decode($datas, true));

This may help you,

V.

Answer (score 0):

Run using url and get data using file_get_content both are different thing.
1) When you run in url it will give you output which is processed by PHP

2) WHen you do file_get_content it will give you code inside that file. you should use curl for what you wants